# mass mail spam when replicating production moodle locally with Docker

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to replicate a Moodle server to my local using Docker and Docker-Compose. I am using moodle 4.1. I extracted from the production server the "moodle" and "moodledata" folder and also the whole database.

I use in the docker-compose the image

```
 "bitnami/mysql" and "bitnami/moodle:4.1
```

With docker-compose I mount both folders. And once I have the 2 containers running, I access inside the container and dump the database.

The thing is that when doing that, it is seen that there is some configuration of the production moodle that is maintained in my local, and from time to time it begins to send about 15-20 emails to registered users about logins, access to courses, etc. ..

Is there any way to prevent these types of emails from being sent while I'm testing locally?

In the docker-compose in "environment" I put the following line, but it doesn't work:

```
MOODLE_DISABLE_SENDING_EMAIL=1
```

Even the config.php in the Moodle folder kept the one from the Docker image, and not the one from the server.

Can you give me any tips on what to do? Or do you need any more information?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: You shouldn't have production data on your laptop (I assume it has personal data and that would be a breach of GDPR). I don't know about moodle, but something I've done when helping orgs that use wordpress, is to create a copy of the DB, run a script that anonymises it and then export the copy. That script should also change any passwords/api keys to external services (e.g. email server/provider)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No problem about that. It hasn't personal data. And the laptop is not my personal laptop. All data that you can see in the DB is the same that everyone can see from his moodle account. I'm gonna investigate about running a script as you say.  Thank you!

Edit: Basically the idea is to be able to have a local copy to recover in case of failure in production

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the SMTP settings have been copied over in the database

In a development environment, I always have these settings in `config.php`

```
// Turn off email
$CFG->noemailever = true;

// When I do want to test emails, divert all the emails
$CFG->divertallemailsto = 'mytestemail@mydomain.com';

// Or for testing without SMTP, use mailsluper
// See https://github.com/mailslurper/mailslurper/wiki/
// Test mailslurper with sendemail -f mytestemail@mydomain.com -t mytestemail@mydomain.com -u "yoohoo" -m "yoohoo2" -s localhost:2500
// View the emails at http://localhost:8080/
//$CFG->smtphosts = 'localhost:2500';
```

Have a look through `config-dist.php` for more details.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer!!
Yes, I tried to put this line that you comment. "$CFG->noemailever = true;"
With this line I was able to deactivate the sending of emails, that is, if I tried to send a message manually, the recipient did not receive it. But instead, the SPAM automated messages kept being sent. I don't know the reason, maybe because the emails are saved in the database and when I do the dump they are sent? Although that with that line should fix it. What can be?

Comment: Yep, that line will stop Moodle from sending emails - settings in config.php will override any settings in the database. I'm guessing the emails had already been sent, so will be in the mail server queue? Unless there is some custom code in Moodle that is sending emails directly?

Comment: What is the email subject and content? Maybe search for the text in the code to see if its a language string - if it is then you can narrow it down.

Comment: It is curious because the emails that are sent are about days and even weeks before, and I think that the same emails are almost always sent. I understand that it is because the copy that I have must have those emails stored in a queue or something similar, correct?

Comment: I have been checking and I see that the email subjects are in different places in the folders, for example moodle.php and also in the cache files. I'm afraid if I don't replicate the cache folder it should fix it, right? Because for example lkos .php files I don't think they affect in this case.I